# How do you minify/obfuscate JavaScript code in a JSP that has JSP/JSTL variables mixed into it?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl, obfuscation

**arrays.jsp:**

```
//...
var x = <c:out value="${x}"/>
<c:if test="${empty doExternal}">
processExternalArrays();
</c:if>
//...
```

I want to minify/obfuscate JavaScript contained in a large JSP file in which numerous JSP/JSTL variables are mixed into the JavaScript code such as in the snippet above.

The code relies on variables populated using server-side logic and then passed to the client-side code, as above.

I'm already minifying my JS files using YUI compressor but I don't know what to do about the JavaScript code in my JSPs.

Is it possible to minify/obfuscate this code, given that it is dynamically created?

Comment: You'd have to have some sort of server facility to do this on-the-fly; is there really enough code on your pages to justify it however?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about doing it on-the-fly on a server. (Yes. There's a lot of code.)

Comment: Well, instead of keeping all that code on your pages, you'd be better off pulling out as much as possible into separate .js files. What you would keep on the pages would be minimal amount of JSP-processed variable declarations. Your separate .js files would just access those by finding them on each page.

Comment: Separating the JS into a separate file would be nice... but seems like a lot of work and extra testing... However, do not keep writing code that generates dynamic javascript statements. You should move towards static js that uses data, instead of dynamically generating it with a server side language, keeping your separate pieces in separate places.

Comment: @Oscar: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best solution for you would be use Granule JSP tag. 
You can download it at
http://code.google.com/p/granule/

code sample is:

```
<g:compress>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="closure/goog/base.js"/>
  <script>
       goog.require('goog.dom');
       goog.require('goog.date');
       goog.require('goog.ui.DatePicker');
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var dp = new goog.ui.DatePicker();
      dp.render(document.getElementById('datepicker'));
  </script>
</g:compress>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [htmlcompressor](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/)? In short it's a:

> Java HTML/XML Compressor is a very
>   small, fast and easy to use library
>   that minifies given HTML or XML source
>   by removing extra whitespaces,
>   comments and other unneeded characters
>   without breaking the content
>   structure.

It's main function is so compress HTML and XML, but it also comes with JSP tags that can be used to compress inline JavaScript blocks by leveraging YUI Compressor. Check out the Google Code page, especially the [Compressing selective content in JSP pages](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/#Compressing_selective_content_in_JSP_pages) section.

Comment: YUI compressor cannot handle JSP tags embedded in the Javascript code itself. In the scenario described by the OP, you have HTML pages which contain inline Javascript fragments which in turn contain embedded JSP tags. When htmlcompressor calls YUI to compress the Javascript fragments, YUI will not be able to handle the embedded JSP tags.

Comment: @Grodriguez True. This is something I overlooked when I posted this answer. I thought that the OP may be able to use the taglib, though, so I figured it's still worth keeping this answer here. The real solution is to not generate a bunch of JavaScript dynamically, but instead generate the data as a JavaScript object and pass it to static JavaScript code as Juan Mendes mentions in the OP comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see other ways than fully delegating the job to pure JS with help of Ajaxical powers in combination with a Servlet which returns the desired information on an Ajax request (in flavor of JSON?).

E.g. in Servlet

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("doExternal", doExternal);
data.put("x", x);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(data)); // Gson is a Java-JSON converter.
```

and in JS (with little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) since it makes the Ajax works less verbose)

```
$.getJSON('servleturl', function(data) {
    var x = data.x;
    if (!data.doExternal) {
        processExternalArrays();
    }
});
```

This way you end up with clean JS without server-side specific clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your output is gzip encoded (apache mod_deflate). Minimizing the html/js first may make it a bit smaller, but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't, or don't want to, move your JavaScript out of your HTML, one possibility would be to create a tag handler that wraps the content of your `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><js:compress>
    ...
</js:compress></script>
```

The handler could probably extend [`SimpleTagSupport`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html). You'd then have to investigate the Java APIs for compressors/minifiers, like YUI Compressor or dojo ShrinkSafe, and use them to process the tag body.

Edit: Sorry, I skimmed the other answers and it appears that Zack Mulgrew might be referencing a taglib that already does exactly what I'm suggesting...

Edit2: Yup, [`JavaScriptCompressorTag`](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/htmlcompressor/taglib/JavaScriptCompressorTag.java). Guess I'll have to up-vote his answer ;-)...